# Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotal is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

After clicking calculate button, its not showing the return value rather showing this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotal is not defined". I am very new to JavaScript. Please help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>2</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <h1> 02 </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <p>You probably want to retire someday so let's get started!</p>
                <form name="retirement savings" action="#" OnClick="calculateTotal(amountNeeded.value, investNo, annContribute,inrate)">
                    How much money do you need to retire: <input type="text" name="savingsGoal"><br><br>
                    Initial Investment: <input type="text" name="initialInvestment"><br><br>
                    Annual Contribution: <input type="text" name="annualContribution"><br><br>
                    Expected Interest Rate: Select from the following please:<br><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="1percent">1 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="1.5percent">1.5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="2percent">2 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="2.5percent">2.5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="3percent">3 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="3.5percent">3.5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="4percent">4 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="4.5percent">4.5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="5percent">5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="5.5percent">5.5 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="6percent">6 Percent<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="interestRate" value="6.5percent">6.5 Percent<br><br>
                        <input type="button" onClick="calculateTotal(savingsGoal.value, initialInvestment, annualContribution,interestRate);" value="Calculate">  <input type="reset">
                </form>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <p>You can retire in years</p>
                <p>with in the bank</p>
                <hr>                
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><br>
        <a href="../index.html">Return to Main Menu</li>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
/*Interest Radio Button*/
var interest_rate= new Array();
interest_rate["1percent"]=1;
interest_rate["1.5percent"]=1.5;
interest_rate["2percent"]=2;
interest_rate["2.5percent"]=2.5;
interest_rate["3percent"]=3;
interest_rate["3.5percent"]=3.5;
interest_rate["4percent"]=4;
interest_rate["4.5percent"]=4.5;
interest_rate["5percent"]=5;
interest_rate["5.5percent"]=5.5;
interest_rate["6percent"]=6;
interest_rate["6.5percent"]=6.5;


function getIntrestRate() {
    var interestRadio = document.getElementsByName('interestRate');

    for (i=0; i < interestRadio.length; i++) {
        if (interestRadio[i].checked) {
            user_input = interestRadio[i].value;
        }
    }

    return interest_rate[user_input];
}

/*Calculation*/

function calculateTotal(savingsGoal.value, initialInvestment.value, annualContribution.value, interstRate.value)(){
 if ((document.calc.savingsGoal.value == null || document.calc.savingsGoal.length == 0) ||
     (document.calc.initialInvestment.value == null || document.calc.initialInvestment.length == 0)||
     (document.calc.annualContribution.value == null || document.calc.rate.annualContribution.length == 0)){
     alert("Please fill in required fields");
     return false;
}

 else
 {
 var amount = document.calc.savingsGoal.value;
 var invest  = document.calc.initialInvestment.value;
 var yearly   = document.calc.annualContribution.value / 1200;
 var interest_rate= document.calc.getInterestRate.value;
 document.calc.pay.value = amount * interest_rate / (1 - (1/(1 + intr), yearly)));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has **`invalid definition`**. You have extra `()` after parameters inside `()`

```
function calculateTotal(savingsGoal.value, initialInvestment.value,
annualContribution.value, interstRate.value)(){
                                          //^^remove this
```

---

**Update**

Few points I just noted which stays invalid in your case. So just go through the code shown in this **[`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7o1ke81b/2/)**. I've updated both `html` and `js`. I've changed the logic of getting values to `function`.. Its a **parameter less `function`** now. Also `getIntrestRate()` is a function and you were trying to access it as a variable/element and the way you were calling it was wrong. There is a spelling mistake i.e. `getInterestRate`. Just go through the fiddle and please note that its not fully `functional`. Not sure what you are getting in `intr` variable at the end.

Comment: Yes, i agree with this. Also you can remove the parameters from the function definition, bacause you don't use them in funtion definition. Use like function calculateTotal(){

Comment: I removed that.but still getting that error. Also this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Answer (score 1):

`calculateTotal` function is not defined properly because there is a syntax error in its signature.

make it

```
function calculateTotal(savingsGoal, initialInvestment, annualContribution, interstRate){
```

you can't access a property of an object here while defining a method.

Also there is an extra parenthesis `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think You Not Include Jquery Library file so you include jquery library file on header its working

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js
```

or  search latest version jquery library file include .